# Watermark strategy for messages with lists of events

Tags: apache-flink

I receive messages over kafka that are basically List<Event> which is then a DataStream<List<Event>>. I use flatmap to turn it into a DataStream<Event>. The question is where and how I apply the WatermarkStrategy. I tried both of the following:

noWatermarks in the DataStream<List<Event>> and forBoundedOutOfOrderness on the DataStream<Event>:

```
    TypeInformation<List<Event>> eventListTypeInfo = new ListTypeInfo<>(Event.class);
    DataStream<List<Event>> eventStream = streamExecutionEnvironment.fromSource(inputKafkaSourceEvents, WatermarkStrategy.noWatermarks(), "Events")
            .returns(eventListTypeInfo);

    DataStream<Event> flatEventStream = eventStream.flatMap(new FlatMapFunction<List<Event>, Event>() {
        @Override
        public void flatMap(List<Event> value, Collector<Event> out) throws Exception {
            value.forEach(out::collect);
        }
    });

    // Assign timestamps based on the event time specified in the event
    val timestampedEventStream = flatEventStream.assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(
            WatermarkStrategy
                    .<Event>forBoundedOutOfOrderness(Duration.ofSeconds(60))
                    .withTimestampAssigner((event, timestamp) -> event.getTimestamp()));
```

forBoundedOutOfOrderness without TimestampAssigner in the DataStream<List<Event>> and forBoundedOutOfOrderness on the DataStream<Event>:

```
    TypeInformation<List<Event>> eventListTypeInfo = new ListTypeInfo<>(Event.class);
    DataStream<List<Event>> eventStream = streamExecutionEnvironment.fromSource(inputKafkaSourceEvents, WatermarkStrategy.forBoundedOutOfOrderness(Duration.ofSeconds(flinkOutOfOrderness)), "Events")
            .returns(eventListTypeInfo);

    DataStream<Event> flatEventStream = eventStream.flatMap(new FlatMapFunction<List<Event>, Event>() {
        @Override
        public void flatMap(List<Event> value, Collector<Event> out) throws Exception {
            value.forEach(out::collect);
        }
    });

    // Assign timestamps based on the event time specified in the event
    val timestampedEventStream = flatEventStream.assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(
            WatermarkStrategy
                    .<Event>forBoundedOutOfOrderness(Duration.ofSeconds(60))
                    .withTimestampAssigner((event, timestamp) -> event.getTimestamp()));
```

No triggers ever get fired in both approaches. The integrations tests work fine.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Edit 1:

Added

```
    streamExecutionEnvironment.getConfig().setAutoWatermarkInterval(5000);
```

and

```
            WatermarkStrategy
                    ...
                    .withIdleness(Duration.ofSeconds(60))
```

I also looked in the Flink UI and it says:

"No Watermark (Watermarks are only available if EventTime is used)"

Answer (score 0):

Currently you're assigning watermarks in two places - once via the source, and the other via `assignTimestampsAndWatermarks()`. You only want to do it once (when defining your source), and use the second version that extracts timestamps.

So do this:

```
    val wmStrategy = WatermarkStrategy
        .<Event>forBoundedOutOfOrderness(
            Duration.ofSeconds(flinkOutOfOrderness))
        .withTimestampAssigner((event, timestamp) -> extractTimestamp(event));

    DataStream<List<Event>> eventStream = streamExecutionEnvironment.fromSource(inputKafkaSourceEvents, wmStrategy, "Events")
            .returns(eventListTypeInfo);
```

where `extractTimestamp(List<Event> events)` is a static method that returns the min timestamp of any event in the list.

A few other bits to clean up...

Get rid of the call to `.assignTimestampsAndWatermarks()`.

Don't bother changing the watermark interval, the default of 200ms is fine.

Only call `.withIdleness()` if you know you've got partitions in your source Kafka topic that can become idle regularly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but that doesn't work: wmStrategy is of type WatermarkStrategy<Event> and it needs WatermarkStrategy<List<Event>>. Like I said I am flatMap afterwards to get rid of hte list and that's why I was doing a assignTimestampsAndWatermarks. Is this not possible?

Comment: Sorry - edited to handle a list of events.